# How to perform conditional function calling in C?

Tags: c, function-pointers, conditional-compilation

So I am doing some work in C where I have implementation of the same function in both assembly and C and I want to compare the performance of C vs assembly implementation. Now for that I would want to be able to compile and call the function conditionally i.e I would want to create a function which would act as an interface between the caller and the right function that I want to call. somehow I am not sure how to do that.
I was thinking somewhere along the line of following:

```
//header file containing the C definition and the assembly definition

void getstate(state* m, int* values);   
extern void kalmanstate(state* m, int* values);
```

Then the caller can include the above header file and pass either &getstate or &kalmanstate.

```
void callTheRightFunction(state* m, int* values, void *fnptr(state*,int*))
{
  *fnptr(m,values);
}
```

However the problem with this is that both getstate and kalmanstate will be compiled which kind of defeats the purpose of my simulation. It does not sound to me the best implementation of the wrapper I want to have. I know conditional execution exists in C but how would I use it to get the right function compile? I mean if I do something like this in the header file:

```
#ifdef __C__FUNC
void getstate(state* m, int *values);
#endif
#ifdef __kalman
void kalmanstate(state *m, int *values)
#endif
```

Then in the caller:
    include "headerfile.h" //include the above header file
    //caller defining _*C*_FUNC
    define __C_FUNC
    callTheRightFunction(m,p,&getstate);
But since I include the header file at the beginning when none of them are defined it would probably not include any of them at all and thus will generate runtime errro.
Any suggestions towards right direction would be appreciated. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Use preprocessor directives: like `#ifdef`

Comment: Don't use leading underscores in global names. They are reserved to the compiler and system implementation. Don't use double-underscore if you want to be compatible with C++ one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your addition to the original question, you were wondering if none of the functions would be compiled. Then you'll have to define `__C__FUNC` or `__kalman` before you include the header file:

```
#define __C__FUNC
#include "header.h"
```

But to avoid this problem when you don't define anything, an approach would be for you to use just one definition, like this, on the SOURCE file:

```
#ifdef __GSTATE_USE_C_FUNCTION
void getstate(state* m, int *values)
{
    // C version
}
#else
void getstate(state *m, int *values)
{
    // Assembly version
}
#endif
```

And on the header file:

```
void getstate(state *m, int *values);
```

(Note the same function name, so you don't need to modify the code when you're calling the function)

But this would only work if you're including the header on the source file where `getstate` is being implemented too. **(*1)**

Then if you forgot to define `__GSTATE_USE_C_FUNCTION` before your header inclusion, the second function would be used, because it triggered the `#else`.

Now, you'd use it like this on a header file that BOTH source files include (that is, the file that implements the function, and the file that uses it):

```
// Comment the line below if you want the other version
#define __GSTATE_USE_C_FUNCTION
```

Of course you'd have to include this header before including the header which contains the prototype declaration.

And on the source file:

```
// Somewhere else on the code where you use the function
getstate(m, values);
```

So you'd only have to change the `#define` line on the global header.

In addition, if your compiler has an option to do preprocessor defining in the command line for it, then you'd not even need to define `__GSTATE_USE_C_FUNCTION` before the `#include`, you'd just use as a command line option, something like this (for example in bcc32):

```
bcc32 /D"__GSTATE_USE_C_FUNCTION" hello.c
```

This would avoid the problem **(*1)**, and you'd not have to make a global header file that both source files have to include.

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem here.

Options:

1. name the ASM and C functions that do the same differently. Use `if` or `switch` or, god forbid, `?:` to call the right one.
2. Same name setup as above. Use a function pointer. If you assign it the address of the ASM function, then function calls through this pointer will go there. If you assign it the address of the C function, the calls will similarly go to the C function.
3. Same name setup as above. Define a macro that would expand to either the ASM or the C function's name. You can define the macro at compile time using the compiler's options. Use that macro in the code that needs to call one of the two functions.
4. Place the ASM and C functions into separate .asm/.s and .c files. When compiling either include one file in the list of compiled files or include the other.